# Engle and Kozicki (1993)'s Serial Correlation Common Feature (SCCF) test

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I have two auto-correlated stationary time series of I(o). I want to look for a common feature in them as per Engle and Kozicki (1993). Specifically I want to see if there is a linear combination of these two series that does not have serial correlation.

Broadly, I am looking for a method to test for long run relationship between two stationary time series just as co-integration is used to test long run relationship between two non-stationary ones.

Comment: Are there any directions in Engle and Kozicki (1993) that you could follow? If so, what is the difficulty? Also, what do you mean by *stationary time series of I(o)*? I suppose that just means *stationary time series* which is the same as saying *the series are I(0)*.